# Data showing defaultly in Jquery slideToggle at starting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In jquery slideToggle(), the I saw data are hiding initially, after triggering events only it will slide down. But in my program it is showing the data always at the initial state. How can I hide that initially, after clicking the button only it will show off.

Comment: Having the code would be really useful

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

```
<a href="#" class="trigger">Click Me</a>
<div class="trigger_container">This is my content</div>
```

### CSS

```
*{margin:0; padding:0; font-family:Arial; font-size:12px;}
.trigger, .trigger_container{margin:10px;}
.trigger{display:block;}
```

### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".trigger_container").hide();
    $('.trigger').click(function(){
        $(".trigger_container").toggle();
    });

});
```

Comment: Please explain your answers. Try-this answers aren't very useful.

Comment: he wants the container will hide while initially. correct??? so, he has to replace this .abc with his own classname....

Comment: I'm not saying your answer is wrong, I'm saying just giving the user some code to try doesn't teach them anything nor does it help future readers with a similar problem fix theirs.

Comment: Gary, check this code and click up arrow, if its useful